# Combining Two Queries From Different Databases

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I have two queries that someone gave me, each giving me data. One being

```
EXEC ('SELECT  ID,
  Date, Type               
  FROM DB2T.BBT') AT DB2
```

and the other being

```
use g_12
select 
    ca.value('(/CA/@ID)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as ID,
    ca.value('(/CA/@Date)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Date,
    ca.value('(/CA/@Type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Type,
from log
```

So I am pretty sure they are from two different databases but I use one set of login credentials for each, so I'm hoping I can somehow combine them, but I can't seem to find the right syntax. Thanks in advance

Comment: You would want to use two queries together with a UNION/UNION ALL. These appear to be on different servers.

Comment: How you are sure that they are on different databases? Anyway, you can always specify database: "select ... from dbName.dbo.log"

Comment: Using EXEC AT indicates that the first query is not on the same server. The second query is just switching to a different database on the same server.

Comment: EXEC AT indicates it's a linked server, which could be pointing to the local server (which doesn't seem very practical lol).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` and specifying the query database name

```
SELECT  
    ID,
    Date, 
    Type               
FROM DB2T.dbo.BBT
UNION ALL
select 
    ca.value('(/CA/@ID)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as ID,
    ca.value('(/CA/@Date)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Date,
    ca.value('(/CA/@Type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Type,
from g_12.dbo.log
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Invalid object name 'DB2.BBT"

Comment: You can try to use `DB2T.dbo.BBT` instead of `DB2.BBT`

Comment: This is close but the first query is running over a link server so it would have to be DB2.DB2T.dbo.BBT. This is four part naming which is [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].[Object]

Comment: @SeanLange now getting the error "The OLE DB provider "..." (removed for privacy purposes) for linked server "DB2" does not contain the table ""DB2T"."dbo"."BBT"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table." I was able to access it using the EXEC statement, so maybe your comment from above has something to do with it.

Comment: Well we are largely guessing here based on experience. It is hard for us to tell you where your databases are located. That would be a LOT easier on your end. :)

Comment: @tjc You wouldn't happen to know the schema for the BBT table? Maybe try DB2T..BBT and use the default schema (if it's not dbo)